# HTML img tag not working

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to display some images on a website, but for some reasons, they are not showing up. This is the code I'm using, which is similar to what I found on the internet, but it just prints Error. How can I fix this?

```
<?php

echo '<img src="D:/website/images/pic.jpg" alt="Error" />';

?>
```

Comment: PHP does not have an IMG tag, that's HTML.

Comment: What is the error? Btw, src urls can not be pathed to a drive letter, if you really want an absolute path it should eb something like, `localhost/website/image...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would not work you should use server URL instead `D:/website/images/pic.jpg` is a system PATH

```
 echo '<img src="http://example.com/website/images/pic.jpg" alt="Error" />';
```

Answer (score 2):

`D:/website/images/pic.jpg` is not a valid URI. The image tag in HTML requires a valid URI for the SRC attribute.

Please see the HTML documentation of your choice (e.g. [Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/element/img)) and provide a [valid URI<sup>*RFC3986*</sup>](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use relative paths:

```
src="/path/to/image.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

images on html should always have protocol prefix like http:// or **file:/// - in your case** so make it like `file:///d:/website/images/pic.jpg` . it still does not work, verify the file exists. file name case does not matter in your windows environment.